# type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'list<latlng>'

Tags: android, flutter

I try to show map polygon. I get list of LatLng data from json.

```
var map = widget.list[widget.index]['map'];
```

Data is already decoded.

Sample:

```
Set<Polygon> myPolygon() {
  Set<Polygon> polygonSet = new Set();
  polygonSet.add(Polygon(
      polygonId: PolygonId('test'),
      points: map,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      strokeColor: Colors.blue,
      fillColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4),));
  return polygonSet;
}
```

This code show error : `type 'string' is not a subtype of the 'List<LatLng>'`

I want output like this:

[image: output]

Comment: add the content of the "map" parameter !

Comment: Can you add all code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this is a correct method or not but it works for me.
Remove Latlng & brackets replace by `"`, then decode the data. after need count of data so I use count variable

```
  var mapdata1 = map.replaceAll('LatLng(', '"');
    var mapdata2 = mapdata1.replaceAll(')', '"');
    var mapdata3 = mapdata2.replaceAll(',]', ']');
    var mapdata4 = json.decode(mapdata3);
    int count = mapdata4.length;
```

then created list latLang variable

```
List<LatLng> latlang =new List();
```

created for loop to fetch list data

```
  for (var i = 0; i <= (count-1); i++) {
    List<String> latlong  =  mapdata4[(i)].split(",");
    double latitude =  double.parse(latlong[0]);
    double longitude = double.parse(latlong[1]);
    latlang.add(LatLng(latitude, longitude));
    }
```

if need to check the output

```
print(latlang);
```

give latLang variable to polygon points

```
Set<Polygon> myPolygon() {
      Set<Polygon> polygonSet = new Set();
      polygonSet.add(Polygon(
          polygonId: PolygonId('test'),
          points: latlang,
          strokeWidth: 2,
          strokeColor: Colors.grey,
          fillColor: Colors.grey.shade700.withOpacity(0.4),));
      return polygonSet;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass `List<LatLng>` to the  points of PolyLine make sure you are getting List inside this `var map = widget.list[widget.index]['map'];`

Comment: I also tried that but still I face that error

Comment: can you show the data of List from where you are getting lat lng??

Comment: LatLng data is getting from database the format of json without decode ```"[LatLng(12.82879876203614, 80.12908793985844),LatLng(12.83370395257544, 80.1245865225792),LatLng(12.839642030904889, 80.12061484158039),]"``` like this

Comment: yes exactly you need to pass this json to points after decode

Comment: i tried but it shows error